# zero Jacobson Radical

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, idempotents

I read in a paper that if every nonzero left (or right) ideal of R (non commutative) contains a nonzero idempotent so $J(R)=0$, but i don't know why? I want understand why happens this.

Thank you

Comment: For future reference: if you remember the document in which you read this thing, you should name it. If you know and you aren't going to name it, then don't even bother mentioning it.  It's just silly to be mysterious when the source could potentially be useful. In this case it isn't actually all that necessary.

Answer (score 1):

One characterization of things in the Jacobson radical is that $x\in J(R)$ iff $1-xr$ is a unit for every $r\in R$.

If $J(R)\neq\{0\}$, and then contained a nonzero idempotent $e$, it would be impossible for $1-e$ to be a unit, because it is a zero divisor on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $e\in J(R)$ is idempotent, $e\ne0$. Then $1-e$ is idempotent as well and $1-e\ne1$, so $1-e$ is not invertible. Take $I$ a maximal right ideal such that $1-e\in I$: then $1=e+(1-e)\in I$: contradiction.

Thus the only idempotent in $J(R)$ is $0$.